# How can multiple static methods use the same generic type?

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparable

While learning from Algorithms (4th edition) (by Robert Sedgewick; Kevin Wayne), I am trying to recreate their codes. They have raw uses of parametrized constructors (generics) which I assume might be because 2011 Java code is different from today's Java code. Here is an example:

```
private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
   return (v.compareTo(w) < 0);
}
```

This works in Java 11/18. But the problem is my IDE highlights this as "raw use of parameterized constructor". According to what I read, I should not be doing this.

But there seems to be no solution where I can both: keep the method static and use generic types for Comparable.

Making the class generic doesn't really help, as the methods then cannot use the generic type of the class

[image]
Error message: 'SelectionSort.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

But adding the generics to individual methods also doesn't work as other methods that I call dont know that their type <T> and the calling method's <T> are the same.
Here is my attempt:

```
public class SelectionSort {
    public static <T> void sort (Comparable<T>[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int min = i;
            for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (less(array[j],array[min]))
                    min = j;
            }
            exch(array, i, min);
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean less(Comparable<T> v, Comparable<T> w) {
        return (v.compareTo(w) < 0);
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void exch(Comparable<T>[] a, int i, int j) {
        Comparable<T> swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
    }
}
```

[image]
Error message: no instance of type variable T exist so that T conforms to Comparable

As you can see Java doesn't know both T's are the same. I feel there is a very simple solution here which I just am not getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Comparable.compareTo()` expects a `T`, not just a `Comparable<T>`. So the second method signature has to be

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean less(T v, T w) {
```

And in order to call it, the first method also needs an array of `T`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort (T[] array) {
```